# Displaying symbolic fonts on CButton mfc

Tags: fonts, mfc, cbutton

I need to display symbolic font on CButton of mfc. How to achieve this? A code sample is more helpful.The symbolic fonts can be from webdings or cusotm installed font.

I tried the below mentioned code but it is not working. I put this code in onpaint method of dialog box.

```
            CWnd *win = GetDlgItem(IDC_BUTTON1);
    CDC *dc = win->GetDC();
    CFont font;
    VERIFY(font.CreateFont(
       12,                        // nHeight
       0,                         // nWidth
       0,                         // nEscapement
       0,                         // nOrientation
       FW_NORMAL,                 // nWeight
       FALSE,                     // bItalic
       FALSE,                     // bUnderline
       0,                         // cStrikeOut
       SYMBOL_CHARSET,              // nCharSet
       OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,        // nOutPrecision
       CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,       // nClipPrecision
       DEFAULT_QUALITY,           // nQuality
       DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_SWISS,  // nPitchAndFamily
       _T("SAPDings")));                 // lpszFacename 

    // Do something with the font just created...
    //CClientDC dc(this);  
    CFont* def_font = dc->SelectObject(&font);
    dc->TextOutW(5, 5, _T("0x0027"), 5);
    dc->SelectObject(def_font);

    // Done with the font.  Delete the font object.
    font.DeleteObject();
```

Comment: The point of this forum is that you try something yourself first and then ask questions if it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, please see my edited problem description

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `CreateFontIndirect` to create the font in the desired size.

Use `CWnd::SetFont` to set the font to the button.

Remember to Keep the font in you parent class as Long as the button or Control exists, were you used the font.

With this method you can only show chars from this font in the Control It is not possible to mix chars from other font with this method.